# Small modification to the Pivot Points indicator in TradingView

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trying to make a small modification to the official Pivot Points Standard indicator in TradingView, but I'm a a bit of a novice when it comes to coding and everything I try doesn't seem to work. I even tried using ChatGPT without success.

During the pre-market trading hours, the pivot point levels are do not get plotted for the trading day until the market open (9:30 am ET).

Since the pivot points formula uses the previous day's data to calculate new pivot levels, I'm trying to modify the code so that they get plotted for the day during the pre-market session before 9:30am ET.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

The code below is the official one for the Pivot Points Standard indicator in TradingView.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Pivot Points Standard", "Pivots", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500)

pivotTypeInput = input.string(title="Type", defval="Traditional", options=["Traditional", "Fibonacci", "Woodie", "Classic", "DM", "Camarilla"])
pivotAnchorInput = input.string(title="Pivots Timeframe", defval="Auto", options=["Auto", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Yearly", "Biyearly", "Triyearly", "Quinquennially", "Decennially"])
maxHistoricalPivotsInput = input.int(title="Number of Pivots Back", defval=15, minval=1, maxval=200, display = display.data_window)
isDailyBasedInput = input.bool(title="Use Daily-based Values", defval=true, display = display.data_window, tooltip="When this option is unchecked, Pivot Points will use intraday data while calculating on intraday charts. If Extended Hours are displayed on the chart, they will be taken into account during the pivot level calculation. If intraday OHLC values are different from daily-based values (normal for stocks), the pivot levels will also differ.")
showLabelsInput = input.bool(title="Show Labels", defval=true, group="labels", display = display.data_window)
showPricesInput = input.bool(title="Show Prices", defval=true, group="labels", display = display.data_window)
positionLabelsInput = input.string("Left", "Labels Position", options=["Left", "Right"], group="labels", display = display.data_window)
linewidthInput = input.int(title="Line Width", defval=1, minval=1, maxval=100, group="levels", display = display.data_window)

DEFAULT_COLOR = #FB8C00
pColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "P‏  ‏  ‏", inline="P", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
pShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="P", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
s1ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "S1", inline="S1/R1" , group="levels", display = display.data_window)
s1ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S1/R1", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r1ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏R1", inline="S1/R1", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r1ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S1/R1", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
s2ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "S2", inline="S2/R2", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
s2ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S2/R2", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r2ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏R2", inline="S2/R2", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r2ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S2/R2", group="levels", tooltip = "Not applicable to DM", display = display.data_window)
s3ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "S3", inline="S3/R3", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
s3ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S3/R3", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r3ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏R3", inline="S3/R3", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r3ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S3/R3", group="levels", tooltip = "Not applicable to DM", display = display.data_window)
s4ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "S4", inline="S4/R4", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
s4ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S4/R4", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r4ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏R4", inline="S4/R4", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r4ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S4/R4", group="levels", tooltip = "Not applicable to: Fibonacci, DM", display = display.data_window)
s5ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "S5", inline="S5/R5", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
s5ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S5/R5", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r5ColorInput = input.color(DEFAULT_COLOR, "‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏  ‏R5", inline="S5/R5", group="levels", display = display.data_window)
r5ShowInput = input.bool(true, "", inline="S5/R5", group="levels", tooltip = "Not applicable to: Fibonacci, Woodie, Classic, DM", display = display.data_window)

type graphicSettings
    string levelName
    color levelColor
    bool showLevel

var graphicSettingsArray = array.from(
      graphicSettings.new(" P", pColorInput, pShowInput),
      graphicSettings.new("R1", r1ColorInput, r1ShowInput), graphicSettings.new("S1", s1ColorInput, s1ShowInput),
      graphicSettings.new("R2", r2ColorInput, r2ShowInput), graphicSettings.new("S2", s2ColorInput, s2ShowInput),
      graphicSettings.new("R3", r3ColorInput, r3ShowInput), graphicSettings.new("S3", s3ColorInput, s3ShowInput),
      graphicSettings.new("R4", r4ColorInput, r4ShowInput), graphicSettings.new("S4", s4ColorInput, s4ShowInput),
      graphicSettings.new("R5", r5ColorInput, r5ShowInput), graphicSettings.new("S5", s5ColorInput, s5ShowInput))

autoAnchor = switch
    timeframe.isintraday => timeframe.multiplier <= 15 ? "1D" : "1W"
    timeframe.isdaily    => "1M"
    => "12M"

pivotTimeframe = switch pivotAnchorInput
    "Auto"      => autoAnchor
    "Daily"     => "1D"
    "Weekly"    => "1W"
    "Monthly"   => "1M"
    "Quarterly" => "3M"
    => "12M"

//@variable The number of years in the selected Pivot period
pivotYearMultiplier = switch pivotAnchorInput
    "Biyearly"       => 2
    "Triyearly"      => 3
    "Quinquennially" => 5
    "Decennially"    => 10
    => 1

//@variable The number of values in the pivots of the selected type
numOfPivotLevels = switch pivotTypeInput
    "Traditional" => 11
    "Camarilla"   => 11
    "Woodie"      => 9
    "Classic"     => 9
    "Fibonacci"   => 7
    "DM"          => 3

type pivotGraphic
    line pivotLine
    label pivotLabel

method delete(pivotGraphic graphic) =>
    graphic.pivotLine.delete()
    graphic.pivotLabel.delete()

var drawnGraphics = matrix.new<pivotGraphic>()

localPivotTimeframeChange = timeframe.change(pivotTimeframe) and year % pivotYearMultiplier == 0
securityPivotTimeframeChange = timeframe.change(timeframe.period) and year % pivotYearMultiplier == 0

pivotTimeframeChangeCounter(condition) => 
    var count = 0
    if condition and bar_index > 0
        count += 1
    count

localPivots = ta.pivot_point_levels(pivotTypeInput, localPivotTimeframeChange)
securityPivotPointsArray = ta.pivot_point_levels(pivotTypeInput, securityPivotTimeframeChange)

securityTimeframe = timeframe.isintraday ? "1D" : timeframe.period
[securityPivots, securityPivotCounter] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, pivotTimeframe, [securityPivotPointsArray, pivotTimeframeChangeCounter(securityPivotTimeframeChange)], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
pivotPointsArray = isDailyBasedInput ? securityPivots : localPivots

//@function Sets the ending points of the currently active pivots to `endTime`.
affixOldPivots(endTime) =>
    if drawnGraphics.rows() > 0
        lastGraphics = drawnGraphics.row(drawnGraphics.rows() - 1)

        for graphic in lastGraphics
            graphic.pivotLine.set_x2(endTime)
            if positionLabelsInput == "Right"
                graphic.pivotLabel.set_x(endTime)

//@function Draws pivot lines and labels from `startTime` to the approximate end of the period.
drawNewPivots(startTime) =>
    
    newGraphics = array.new<pivotGraphic>()

    for [index, coord] in pivotPointsArray
        levelSettings = graphicSettingsArray.get(index)
        if not na(coord) and levelSettings.showLevel
            lineEndTime = startTime + timeframe.in_seconds(pivotTimeframe) * 1000 * pivotYearMultiplier
            pivotLine = line.new(startTime, coord, lineEndTime, coord, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color=levelSettings.levelColor, width=linewidthInput)
            pivotLabel = label.new(x = positionLabelsInput == "Left" ? startTime : lineEndTime,
                               y = coord,
                               text = (showLabelsInput ? levelSettings.levelName + " " : "") + (showPricesInput ? "(" + str.tostring(coord, format.mintick) + ")" : ""),
                               style = positionLabelsInput == "Left" ? label.style_label_right : label.style_label_left,
                               textcolor = levelSettings.levelColor,
                               color = #00000000,
                               xloc=xloc.bar_time)
            
            newGraphics.push(pivotGraphic.new(pivotLine, pivotLabel))
    
    drawnGraphics.add_row(array_id = newGraphics)

    if drawnGraphics.rows() > maxHistoricalPivotsInput
        oldGraphics = drawnGraphics.remove_row(0)
        
        for graphic in oldGraphics
            graphic.delete()


localPivotDrawConditionStatic = not isDailyBasedInput and localPivotTimeframeChange
securityPivotDrawConditionStatic = isDailyBasedInput and securityPivotCounter != securityPivotCounter[1]

var isMultiYearly = array.from("Biyearly", "Triyearly", "Quinquennially", "Decennially").includes(pivotAnchorInput)
localPivotDrawConditionDeveloping = not isDailyBasedInput and time_close == time_close(pivotTimeframe) and not isMultiYearly 
securityPivotDrawConditionDeveloping = false

if (securityPivotDrawConditionStatic or localPivotDrawConditionStatic)
    affixOldPivots(time)
    drawNewPivots(time)

// If possible, draw pivots from the beginning of the chart if none were found
var FIRST_BAR_TIME = time
if (barstate.islastconfirmedhistory and drawnGraphics.columns() == 0)

    if not na(securityPivots) and securityPivotCounter > 0
        if isDailyBasedInput
            drawNewPivots(FIRST_BAR_TIME)
        else 
            runtime.error("Not enough intraday data to calculate Pivot Points. Lower the Pivots Timeframe or turn on the 'Use Daily-based Values' option in the indicator settings.")
    else
        runtime.error("Not enough data to calculate Pivot Points. Lower the Pivots Timeframe in the indicator settings.")
```

I tried using "request.security" but that's probably wrong (used ChatGPT).